# The Fourier Series Of This Triangle Wave

Tags: matlab, fourier-series

I am using matlab to study digital signalling and have come across a problem which i was wondering if anyone with more experience could help me with.

I need to work derive the Fourier series of a triangle wave that i have generated, I just do not know how to actually go about this problem in Matlab.

I am generating a 100hz Triangle signal using the following code:

```
t = 0:1/10000:1;
f=100;
x1 = sawtooth(2*pi*f*t, 0.5);
plot(t,x1); 
axis([0 0.10 -1 1]);
```

Now how should i go about deriving the Fourier series of this signal, i am completely lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Triangle](http://demo.activemath.org/ActiveMath2/LeAM_calculusPics/TriangleWave.png?lang=en) and [sawtooth](http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/GeneralInterest/Harrison/Vibrations/transp11.7.gif) are not the same waveform. Which is the one you want to analyze?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Wikipedia's [Fourier Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) page.  Their "Example 1" shows how to derive the Fourier series of a sawtooth wave.  All you have to do is normalize the results for your particular time and amplitude values.

Answer (score 0):

If the modulus of the slope of your sawtooth voltage is A, then your Fourier Co-efficient, if you are talking about a continuous time fourier series, is

Cn=-(A*To/((n*pi)^2))*((Sin((n*pi)/2))^2)

Hint: double differentiate your signal till you end up with dirac delta functions, they are easy to modify.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to calculate the FFT of this signal in MATLAB? This would be like this:

```
N_fft = 2^15; %Just an FFT size
x1_fft = fft(x1, N_fft); %Take the FFT.
plot(abs(x1_fft));
```

Comment: This is not the same as computing Fourier Series. The difference is that Fourier Series comes from continuous Fourier Transform, while FFT comes from discrete Fourier Transform.

Comment: @Phonon: Aren't they identical except for the Fourier Series having an infinite number of harmonics?

Comment: @Phonon This is why I asked him if what he really wants is to compute the FFT of the signal, and not really 'deriving the fourier series'.

Comment: @Mohammad If you zoom in on one of the peaks in your plot, it's not really a peak. It's a lobe. That's why I would be more careful. You're essentially windowing your signal with a rectangle and getting characteristic of a sinc in your frequency plot.

Comment: @Phonon Sorry Im not following you... the OP sounds like he just wants to FFT his signal in MATLAB, and being new to the field might be (understandably) getting exact fourier lingo mixed up, what with distinctions between fourier co-efficients VS an FFT, VS a CFT, etc etc. We need more feedback from him.

Comment: -1 The $k$-th Fourier coefficient for a periodic signal of period $T$ is $$c_k = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T x(t)\exp(-j2\pi kt/T) \mathrm dt$$ while the $k$-th DFT coefficient (which is what the FFT algorithm computes) is $$X[k] = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]\exp(-j2\pi kn/N).$$ Unless you connect up the values of $T$ and $N$ and $x[n]$ and $x(t)$ and explain how your FFT is computing the Fourier coefficients, or reasonable approximations thereto, your answer is meaningless.  See also Phonon's comment.

Comment: Guys, take the chatter and finger pointing to a chatroom. I'm going to wipe out the unconstructive comments in an hour (you're welcome to remove them yourself before that). Mohammed, I do agree with users here that the OP has clearly stated that they want to calculate the Fourier series, which is different from an FFT. Now, you might be correct that they are unclear about the difference between the two and might have actually intended the FFT. But we do not know that yet, and the right place to ask that is in the comments. Please confirm from the OP as to what they really want and then answer.

Comment: @yoda "and might have actually intended the FFT"... right, which is why I put that caveat at the top of the code. This has been the last straw with Mr Dilip, Im taking this to the meta.

Comment: @Mohammad Meta is the right place for this. I would still urge you to not indulge in specific finger pointing and keep the discussion (on meta) focused on the specific behaviour that you have an issue with and not a specific user.